# stand alone AS2 client for transferring file

Tags: sftp, actionscript-2, file-transfer

I need to transfer file (xml) to AS2 server. I am not so good at this communication channel, but I need to do it programmatically. For example sending to SFTP I am using this code:

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
.......
public void uploadViaSFTP (String fileToUpload, String sftp_host, String sftp_user, String sftp_psw) 
    {
        int    SFTPPORT = 22;
        Session     session     = null;
        Channel     channel     = null;
        ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;

        try{
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            session = jsch.getSession(sftp_user,sftp_host,SFTPPORT);
            session.setPassword(sftp_psw);
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            //this line should be used only for testing, not for production
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
            channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;
            channelSftp.cd("/");
            File f = new File(fileToUpload);
            channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(f), f.getName());
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

But now I need to do same for AS2. What library I could use (openAS2)? Is there a simple method to transfer like it does for SFTP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use standard HTTPS components and S/MIME attachment, since AS2 is a security layer and usage specification on top of HTTP or HTTPS.

I'd start with (https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-https-client-httpsurlconnection-example/), the AS2 specification (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4130.txt) , and this example from github: (https://github.com/protocol7/smime-java-example)